# What is your choice, pain or headache or trouble?

Tags: word-choice

Person A: Could you come to my home to pick up this document?

Person B: Sorry, it is sort of "headache" or "pain" or "trouble", because your home is too far away from my home.

Are they all correct? If so, which one is more common in colloquial AmE?

Answer (score 2):

They are all fairly common and normal-sounding words used to describe this sort of situation.  Note you can say something is "a pain" or "a headache" but not "a trouble" (it's a mass noun).

I would *guess* from most to least common, when dealing with troublesome tasks: pain, headache, trouble (I could easily be quite wrong here).  When dealing with non-troublesome tasks: "no trouble" is common, but pain and headache are not so commonly used in similar negations.

Examples:

Oh, that would be a pain.

That's a bit of a headache.

Can you see any trouble with that?

That's no trouble.

Comment: Reading this again I realize that 'headache' usually describes a situation that requires thought to resolve, which is not quite right for the situation described in the question.